# Trim rows and tranpose in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, trim

I'm trying to trim this rows horizontaly and then transpose the values in two columns with this formula:

=FILTER(7:8, TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(7:8),,9^9)))<>"") But it looks like it don't do anything. Here is the data:

Help with this please

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following formula should produce the behaviour you want:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(7:8),"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: I tried but not the expected results, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can try `FILTER()` function.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A7:I8,A7:I7<>""))
```

Also could use `QUERY()` like-

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A7:J8),"where Col1 is not null",0)
```

[image]